# NestJS is closing connection?

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a NestJS app (+web frontend) and in my localhost I use cloud sql proxy to connect to MySQL database in Google Cloud.

When I start the NestJS app in localhost I create the connection

```
2021/08/20 13:31:00 New connection for "XXX" 
2021/08/20 13:31:00 refreshing ephemeral certificate for instance XXX 
2021/08/20 13:31:00 Scheduling refresh of ephemeral certificate in 23h55m0.2025973s
```

After NestJS has started I get this:

```
2021/08/20 13:31:01 Client closed local connection on 127.0.0.1:3306
```

when I load the web app and it connects I get connection refused from my APIs to NestJS backend

Everything worked fine up until a few days. I can't figure this out since I have not changed anything that in my mind affects the connections

I am using TypeOrm and I don't have any explicit connection settings so I am going with the default ones. It should handle the connection pooling

I can connect with MySQL workbench thru the cloud sql proxy just fine

Thanks,

Jani

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out, it has nothing to do with the connection but rather with the service dependencies in NestJS. I had some circular dependencies but NestJS did not give any error about these. During startup loading of the modules and routes just stopped without any error.

I created a shared module which I then imported as a dependency to the other modules. It seemed to fix the issue.